# Exotic coupling

Tags: electromagnetism, hamiltonian, interactions

I have encountered the minimal coupling between a field and charges before $$H = \frac{1}{2m}(p-qA)^2,$$

whereby I am considering the classical case.

The description minimal leads me to ask if there exist [exotic couplings](http://www.google.com/#q=exotic+couplings) (non-minimal)? Could some examples of such couplings be discussed?

Comment: Some case of a non relativistic coupling is discussed in the section about "electronium" here http://arxiv.org/abs/0806.2635